# Suricata Signature Explanation

Tags: http, snort

I am trying to figure out some Suricata(or Snort) signatures, more specifically, what they mean, what they prevent and have some problems about meanings of keywords. I will not write irrelevant parts.
For instance:

```
 ...flow:established,to_server;  content:"/advert/get"; nocase; http_uri; pcre:"/\/advert\/get(?:ads|kws)(?:\.cgi)?\?(?:d|[ex]_dp_)id=/Ui";  classtype:trojan-activity; sid:2013983; rev:6;)
```

> "Produce alarm if payload contains `/advert/get` path and matches with pcre expression"

Which part exactly should pair with that regular expression? URI itself(`advert/get`) or after `/advert/get/.....` ?

Second one,

```
flow:established,to_server; content:"POST"; nocase; http_method; content:"/check.php?tcpc="; http_uri; content:!"User-Agent|3a|"; http_header; ...
```

> "Produce alarm if http request method is post and payload contains /check.php?tcpc=" .

What does second content catch? I interpreted as "produce alarm if user agent is not empty in http header" Is it true?

And as a last one, assume you have multiple contents like

```
 content:"&AFFILIATE="; http_uri; content:"&ID="; http_uri; content:"&ERROR=0
```

Should I interpret as "and" or "or".

> "Produce alarm if content contains &AFFILIATE AND &ID AND &ERROR" Is it sensible?

I am very confused and its documentation doesn't help, so any answer or resource that explains content more detailed would be awesome.

Comment: From what I have gathered I would treat this as an "and/or" so if it contains any of these or any combination of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have interpreted the first one correctly.

The second one:

```
flow:established,to_server; content:"POST"; nocase; http_method; \
content:"/check.php?tcpc="; http_uri;                            \
content:!"User-Agent|3a|"; http_header; ...
```

This alerts if: method is POST, URI contains /check.php?tcpc= and it does NOT have a User-Agent. The ! in front of the content string means that it is a negated match. So it matches if it's absent from the inspected traffic.

Third one:

```
content:"&AFFILIATE="; http_uri; content:"&ID="; http_uri; content:"&ERROR=0
```

This matches if *all* of the contents are present. This is generally true for Suricata rules. All of the conditions have to match for a rule to generate an alert.

Suricata rule language documentation can be found here: https://redmine.openinfosecfoundation.org/projects/suricata/wiki/Suricata_Rules

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i wasn't expecting that much detailed one which adresses all questions to be honest.